# Get all tds from a tr with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to automate a process with Selenium but I am a bit stuck, I explain what I want to do:

1. I find a td with specific text inside (done)
2. From that td, I get its tr looking for xpath in it (done).
3. Now, inside that tr, there are 12 td, I want to get the penultimate one, but I don't know how to do it anymore.

This is the code of what I comment:

```
td = WebDriverWait(driver, 180).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'//td[text()="{profile}"]')))
tr = td.find_element_by_xpath("../..")
```

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work for me:

```
# this
td_11 = tr.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[11]")
# this
td_11 = td.find_element_by_xpath('../..').find_element_by_xpath(".//td[2]")
# and this
td_11 = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name("td") # then get the 11
```

but i can't get the td i want ...

The structure of the tr is as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Use `find_elements_by_xpath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get to the `td's` which are in `tr` and if this represent the tr

```
tr = td.find_element_by_xpath("../..")
```

you could do :

```
all_tds = tr.find_elements_by_xpath(".//child::td")
```

this would represent all the td's that you've inside tr.

Now to go to `penultimate` , I do not know how does it look like in HTML. but if it is an attribute then you can try with below code :

```
penultimate_td = tr.find_element_by_xpath(".//child::td[@penultimate]")
```

basically I need to see the HTML for `penultimate` to give you reliable locator.

or since you have `all_tds`  which is a list in Python, you can iterate that as well to get the each web element.

Comment: penultimate is the td before the last. That is, inside the tr there are 12 td, I want the number 11.

Comment: `all_tds[11]` should represent that td then, since it's a list you can find it using index itself.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!
If it's not a bother, could you tell me how everything would be done along the same lines? Out of curiosity. I am learning and I do not know very well how to do the same xpath to find a complete path.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question properly, but if you are asking this `all_tds = tr.find_elements_by_xpath(".//child::td")` to align with whatever you had, we could this : `all_tds  = WebDriverWait(driver, 180).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'//td[text()="{profile}"]'))).find_element_by_xpath("../..").find_elements_by_xpath(".//child::td")` or even this should work too `all_tds  = WebDriverWait(driver, 180).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'//td[text()="{profile}"]'))).find_elements_by_xpath("../..//child::td")`

Comment: It was just what I was asking, thank you! I think it's a little less readable that way.